# How to stop duplicate emails from active users?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need a little guidance!

I have created a simple script for a Google Spreadsheet that is designed to email a user when  a specific criteria is met and mark that row as "Emailed"; it runs on the onEdit trigger and works great. 
However, if more than one trigger enabled user has the sheet open at the same time it will send the same email from each account.

I tried using:

```
function onChange(e) {
    if (ROW HASN'T BEEN EMAILED ALREADY) {
       if (3 CELLS IN A ROW HAVE CONTENT) {
           if (Session.getActiveUser().getEmail() == e.user.getUserLoginId()) {
              SEND THE EMAIL
              MARK ROW AS EMAILED
           }
        }
    }
}
```

So that only the user that made the change sends the email, however, all users still send the email. I have compared the values `Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()` and `e.user.getUserLoginId()` produce manually and in theory it should work ... though clearly I am doing something wrong!

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bit of a confusing topic but I believing this is functioning correctly.

Here are some details.

1. In the `onChange(e)` function, `e.user` will always be the person that "owns" the document. Look towards the bottom of [this page](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_events) on events in the document. In essence, you cannot figure out which user's change caused the trigger to fire.
2. When there are two users each with a trigger on the `onEdit` event, then both of the triggers will run each time (essentially the function runs twice) even if only one of the user has the spreadsheet open. However, per #1 you can't within the trigger function run figure out which user's change caused the `onEdit` event

You'll have to rethink your workflow a bit, perhaps as a [timed trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_clocktriggerbuilder) that checks every hour for people to be emailed. Another option is to only have one trigger that runs as the document owner and you can perform the checking logic there. Hope this makes sense.